# loop over forms collection and add data to list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code, which I'm using to get the values from a forms collection

```
List<FlowSettings> lst = new List<FlowSettings>();
string[] IsVisible  =  fc["IsVisible"].Split(',');
string[] Editable   = fc["Editable"].Split(',');
string[] Revisable  = fc["Revisable"].Split(',');
string[] tbl        = fc["tblId"].Split(',');
```

The above arrays are just for me to ensure that I'm getting the data as expected. My problem is, I can loop over the forms collection, but cannot get the values out and add to my list.

```
foreach (var _key in fc.Keys)
{
    var _value = fc[_key.ToString()];
    //lst.Add(new FlowSettings { TblId = Convert.ToInt32(_value[0]),  ChxIsVisible =
    Convert.ToBoolean(_value[1]),
    ChxEditable = true, 
    ChxRevisable = true
    });          
}
```

The values in IsVisible etc have 10 rows which are bool and tbl is an int

Can anyone let me know what I'm missing

--------------Extra code-------------------

```
public ActionResult FlowItems(FormCollection fc)
```

lst is in the foreach loop

Comment: can you show what `fc` looks like.. you declare an instance of `lst` but where in the code are you actually using it.. the existing code that you have is not very clear.. can you show what values are in `fc` that you are splitting as to gain a better understanding..? thanks

Comment: @MethodMan fc is in ActionResult, and lst is in foreach loop

Comment: it would be nice to see an example of what the values look like to alleviate all the guess work..

Comment: tblId is int, IsVisible etc are bool

Comment: example tblId = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 IsVisible = true, false, true, true, false etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormCollection` does not implement the `IDictionary(TKey,TValue)` interface, so you need to loop through and get the values.

Data

```
public class FlowSettings
{
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
    public bool Editable { get; set; }
    public bool Revisable { get; set; }
    public int TblId { get; set; }
}

private bool ParseBool(string value)
{
    return Convert.ToBoolean(EmptyToFalse(value));
}

private int ParseInt(string value)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(EmptyToInvalid(value));
}

private string EmptyToFalse(string value)
{
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? bool.FalseString : value;
}

private string EmptyToInvalid(string value)
{
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? "-1" : value;
}
```

Create

```
var col1 = new NameValueCollection
{
    { "IsVisible", "True" },
    { "Editable", "True" },
    { "Revisable", "True" },
    { "tblId", "100" },
};

var col2 = new NameValueCollection
{
    { "IsVisible", "True" },
    { "Editable", "" },
    { "Revisable", "True" },
    { "tblId", "101" },
};

var formCollection = new FormCollection
{
    col1,
    col2
};

var length =
    formCollection
        .Cast<string>()
        .Select(entry => formCollection.GetValues(entry).Length)
        .Max();
```

Loop

```
var items = new List<FlowSettings>();

for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    var flowSettings = new FlowSettings
    {
        IsVisible = ParseBool(formCollection.GetValues("IsVisible")[i]),
        Editable = ParseBool(formCollection.GetValues("Editable")[i]),
        Revisable = ParseBool(formCollection.GetValues("Revisable")[i]),
        TblId = ParseInt(formCollection.GetValues("tblId")[i]),
    };

    items.Add(flowSettings);
}
```

There is a caveat to this approach. If there is data missing from `col1` or `col2`. e.g.

```
var col3 = new NameValueCollection
{
    { "IsVisible", "True" },
    { "Editable", "" },
    // { "Revisable", "True" }, Missing this entry
    { "tblId", "102" },
};
```

Then the loop with be out of bounds.

Comment: Hi @Romoku thanks, that works, I'm now a junior programmer with a bit more knowledge :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that the collection contains values that are comma-delimited (I'm assuming that because of the `Split()` at the beginning your question) but in the for loop you are using the value directly without splitting on commas. So I guess it would be trying to create a bool out of the 2nd character (index of 1) of the value.

Try this instead:

```
        foreach (var _key in fc.Keys)
        {
            var _value = fc[_key.ToString()];
            string[] tokenized = _value.Split(',');
            bool b = Convert.ToBoolean(tokenized[1]);
        }
```